# Text File to String in iOS

Tags: ios, string, label

I am starting a very simple learning application and I am working with NSURLConnection and have started looking into reading the contents of a file for example, www.funnynewsletter.tk/files/files.txt and reading them as a String into Objective C.

I am wondering how to do this and print the saved string onto a label, "label".

Can anyone help me out?

Here is my current code.

```
- (void) viewDidUnLoad
{
NSError* e;
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:@"http://funnynewsletter.tk/files/files.txt"];
if(e != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error");
}
label.text = self.str;
}
```

This has errors on line 4 and 8. I have no clue what is going on. Can anyone help?

Comment: it should be str not self.str

Comment: Write in ViewDidLoad.And not self.str it's just str

Comment: Thanks. :) That fixed that error. I am still getting a SIGABRT when I run the app. @pm444

Comment: have u added the label to the storyboard and have u added the iboutlet to the label, so it will respond accordingly?

Comment: Question, where are y r u using error variable?

Comment: @Robin I am going to ad a failure message eventually. :)

Comment: @lakesh I have added the iboutlet to the label.

Comment: - (void) viewDidUnLoad to - (void) viewDidLoad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending `NSString` instead of `NSURL`.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
    {
    //NSError* e;
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://funnynewsletter.tk/files/files.txt"]];
    //if(e != nil) {
    //    NSLog(@"Error");
    //}
    label.text = str;
    }
```

try this...

Comment: That fixes the primary issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this method

```
+ (id)stringWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path
                  usedEncoding:(NSStringEncoding *)enc
                         error:(NSError **)error
```

The one you are using is deprecated and has no encoding, error support.

```
- (void) viewDidUnLoad
{
   NSError* e;
   NSString *str = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"http://funnynewsletter.tk/files/files.txt"
                    usedEncoding:(NSASCIIStringEncoding   //OR NSUTF8StringEncoding if utf8 not ASCII
                    error:&e];
if(e != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error");
}
else
   label.text =str;
}
```